# Does Entity Framework use database connection pooling? and is it by default?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I have been searching for a while about how EF utilizes connections to SQL Server DB, and whether it is using Connection pools under the hood, but I couldn't find any details about that.

Comment: what is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: I am not seeing a problem yet, I am just concerned because I am building a website with EF as my backend, and I didn't use it before so I wanted to tie up some loose ends in my design review.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Connection pooling is handled by the underlying datasource provider, and not by the Entity Framework.  The MS SQL provider, for example, supports and uses connection pooling by default.

[Using Connection Pooling with SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28VS.80%29.aspx)

is a good reference.